# Invalid JSON when serialized in MVC c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, jquery-ui

I'm using Jquery UI to have an auto-complete function on a textbox in my site, JSON is serialised in the MVC ViewModel and then used in the view.
The JSON isnt being made correctly at runtime.
The in-browser console returns the following

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

I haven't got it working with my own data yet so the item names are still relevant to the JqueryUI example, with my own JSON data.

**The View (Razor)**

```
<script>
  $(function () {
      var projects = @Model.TeamsAsJson


      $("#project").autocomplete({
          minLength: 0,
          source: projects,
          focus: function (event, ui) {
              $("#project").val(ui.item.TeamName);
              return false;
          },
          select: function (event, ui) {
              $("#project").val(ui.item.TeamName);
              $("#project-id").val(ui.item.TeamName);
              $("#project-description").html(ui.item.AreaName);
              $("#project-icon").attr("src", "images/" + ui.item.icon);

              return false;
          }
      })
      .autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
          return $("<li>")
            .append("<a>" + item.TeamName + "<br>" + item.AreaName + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
      };
  });
  </script>

<div id="project-label">Select a project (type "j" for a start):</div>
<img id="project-icon" src="images/transparent_1x1.png" class="ui-state-default"    alt="">
<input id="project">
<input type="hidden" id="project-id">
<p id="project-description"></p>
```

**The ViewModel**

```
 public String TeamsAsJson{ get{
          JavaScriptSerializer Serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
          return Serializer.Serialize(TeamHelpers.GetAllTeams());
      }
          private set { TeamsAsJson = value; }
      }
```

**The Serialized JSON**

```
[{&quot;TeamID&quot;:1,&quot;TeamName&quot;:&quot;Bilborough Broncos&quot;,&quot;ClubID&quot;:null,&quot;LeagueID&quot;:null,&quot;IsPremium&‌​quot;:false,&quot;PremiumLength&quot;:null,&quot;PremiumStart&quot;:null,&quot;Co‌​untryID&quot;:&quot;GB&quot;,&quot;AreaName&quot;:&quot;Nottingham&quot;,&quot;Cl‌​ub&quot;:null,&quot;League&quot;:null}]
```

**What It should be**

```
[{"TeamID":1,"TeamName":"Bilborough Broncos","ClubID":null,"LeagueID":null,"IsPremium":false,"PremiumLength":null,"PremiumStart":null,"CountryID":"GB","AreaName":"Nottingham","Club":null,"League":null}]
```

Comment: What does the controller look like.  It already appears you are incorrectly converting the object to JSON using non-standard MVC means.

Comment: I have moved your self-answer to the answers section. In the future, please keep the question and answers separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c# variable was being html encoded. The fix was:

```
var projects = @Html.Raw(Model.TeamsAsJson)
```

<sub>Note: this was extracted from the question and posted here on the OP's behalf.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1:**

Try using `JSON.parse` as :-

```
$("#project").autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: projects,
      focus: function (event, ui) {
          ui=JSON.parse(ui.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));
          $("#project").val(ui.item.TeamName);
          return false;
      },
      select: function (event, ui) {
          ui=JSON.parse(ui.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));
          $("#project").val(ui.item.TeamName);
          $("#project-id").val(ui.item.TeamName);
          $("#project-description").html(ui.item.AreaName);
          $("#project-icon").attr("src", "images/" + ui.item.icon);

          return false;
      }
  })
```

**Answer 2:**

**ViewModel:**

```
public String TeamsAsJson{ get{
          JavaScriptSerializer Serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
          return Serializer.Serialize(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TeamHelpers.GetAllTeams(), Formatting.None));
      }
          private set { TeamsAsJson = value; }
      }
```

Comment: same error... JSON is actually returning

`var projects = [{&quot;TeamID&quot;:1,&quot;TeamName&quot;:&quot;Bilborough Broncos&quot;,&quot;ClubID&quot;:null,&quot;LeagueID&quot;:null,&quot;IsPremium&quot;:false,&quot;PremiumLength&quot;:null,&quot;PremiumStart&quot;:null,&quot;CountryID&quot;:&quot;GB&quot;,&quot;AreaName&quot;:&quot;Nottingham&quot;,&quot;Club&quot;:null,&quot;League&quot;:null}]` at runtime instead of what was mentioned

Comment: then try this ui = JSON.parse(ui)...in select and focus...instead of applying it on individual elements...

Comment: it wont let me, when i do that, it says "{ expected"

Comment: same error is being thrown. however, it is being thrown on declaration of the var. line 62 in my code which is "var projects = @Model.TeamsAsJson"

Comment: see...updated answer...@user3381024...

Comment: above answer will work...just see there must be problems with brackets...@user3381024...

Comment: take @Model.TeamsAsJson inside single quotes as...'@Model.TeamsAsJson'

Comment: fixed now, see updated question

Comment: @user3381024...see answer 2 it will work....

Comment: @user3381024....problem solved..????